# What's the measure of the segment $MN$ in the question below?

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

For reference:(exact copy of the question) In the triangle $ABC$, $H$ is the orthocenter, $M$ and $N$ are midpoints of $AC$ and $BH$ respectively.
Calculate $MN$, if $AH=14$ and $BC=48$ (answer: $25$)

My progress..my drawing according to the statement and the relationships I found

[image]

we have several similarities
$\triangle AKC \sim \triangle BKH\\
\triangle AHE \sim BHK \sim \triangle BCE\implies\\
\frac{14}{48} = \frac{HE}{CE}=\frac{AE}{BE}\\\frac{BH}{48} = \frac{KH}{CE}=\frac{BK}{BE}\\
\frac{14}{BH} = \frac{HE}{HK}=\frac{AE}{BK}\\
\triangle MKC \sim \triangle NKH\\
\triangle NBK \sim \triangle MAK$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through B draw BX // AK. Through H, draw HY // AB.

[image]

If BX meets HY at Z, then ABZH is a parallelogram with BZ = AH = 14. Since N is the midpoint of the diagonal BH, AZ will go through N such that AN = NZ.

Applying the midpoint theorem to the purple triangle, we have $NM = 0.5CZ = 0.5\sqrt (BZ^2 + BC^2)$

Comment: Nice construction!

Answer (score 2):

$$MN=\sqrt{\left(\vec{MN}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{AH}+\vec{CB}\right)\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}(14^2+48^2)}=25.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\triangle AFH \sim \triangle BFC$

$FC = \frac{48}{14} HF, BF = \frac{48}{14} AF$

$2 FN = BF+HF = \frac{24}{7} AF + HF \tag1$

$\triangle ABF \sim \triangle HCF$

$\frac{CF}{HF} = \frac{BF}{AF} \implies CF = \frac{48}{14} HF$

$2 FM = CF - AF = \frac{24}{7} HF - AF \tag2$

Squaring $1$ and $2$ and adding,

$4 (FN^2 + FM^2) = \left(\frac{25}{7}\right)^2 (AF^2 + HF^2) = \left(\frac{25}{7}\right)^2 \cdot 14^2$

$MN^2 = 25^2 \implies MN = 25$

Comment: (+1) While trying to solve this problem, I noted that $AH^2+BC^2=BH^2+AC^2$ Is this a special property or just a coincidence?

Comment: @ACB no it is not a coincidence. It would hold true even if the given lengths were different. If you are familiar with vectors, $\vec {AH} = \vec {AF} + \vec {FH}, \vec {BC} = \vec {BF} + \vec {FC}$. So, $\vec {AH} + \vec {BC} = (\vec {AF} + \vec {FC}) + (\vec {BF} - \vec {CF}) = \vec {AC} + \vec {BH}$. So, $|\vec {AH} + \vec {BC}| = |\vec {AC} + \vec {BH}|$. Now as $AH \perp BC$. $\vec {AH} \cdot \vec {BC} = 0$. Similarly $\vec {AC} \cdot \vec {BH} = 0$. That leads to $AH^2 + BC^2 = BH^2 + AC^2$

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for a proof. And yes, I am familiar with vectors, so the above makes sense. It seems that Michael Rozenberg is using this method.

Comment: @ACB yes in this case, it is more straightforward to show $MN = 25$ using vectors than similarity of triangles and what I did with it but I wanted to avoid vectors. But the other answer with parallelogram construction is nice!

Comment: It's the solution I tried to follow...great resolution...thankful